# Whats the correct answers to this question?

Tags: grammar

Please look at this question.

> Ich habe eine biografie von Einstein, ein__ weltweit__ beruehmt__
>   Physiker, gelesen.

According to what I have learned, this sentence equals

> Ich habe eine biografie von Einstein gesehen, ein__ weltweit__
>   beruehmt__ Physiker.

So my answer would be:

> weltweiter beruehmte Physiker

however, my teacher gave me this answer:

> einem weltweit beruehmten Physiker

This makes me puzzled. What is the right answer?

Comment: How did you arrive at "weltweiter beruehmte Physiker"?

Comment: You write *Please look at this question.* but there is no question. We have to guess it - okay, there are not so many options - but could you please explain in more detail?

Answer (score 3):

Your teacher is correct. "Ich habe eine Biographie (was) von (wem) gelesen." Der weltweit berühmte Physiker wird hier im Dativ verwendet und muss entsprechend dekliniert werden: eine Biographie von einem weltweit berühmten Physiker. Das "weltweit" ist eine Ergänzung zum "berühmt" und wird daher nicht verändert.

Comment: 'Ich werde ihm,einem heimatlosen Junge, helfen'. Is this right?

Comment: @Null * _Jungen_ other than that it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If the following apposition includes an article (here: *ein* Physiker), the apposition is in the same case as the reference expression:

> … von Einstein *(dative)* → einem Physiker *(dative)*
>
> eine Biografie von Einstein, einem Physiker

If the following apposition does not include any article, the apposition frequently is in the nominative case:

> nach Meinung Einsteins, eines Physikers, wurde …
>
> nach Meinung Einsteins, Physiker, wurde …

However, if any confusion is possible, the apposition shall be in the same case as the reference expression:

> der Sohn Einsteins, Physiker (= der Sohn ist Physiker)
>
> der Sohn Einsteins, [eines] Physikers (= Einstein ist Physiker)